# Carpeta oculta en proyecto Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

Tengo un proyecto de biblioteca de clases en Visual Studio 2017 y cuando quiero crear una carpeta con un nombre concreto me dice que no puedo por que ya existe y yo esa carpeta no la veo ni en el proyecto en Visual Studio ni en el explorador de archivos en la carpeta donde se guarda el proyecto.
Donde busca VS esa carpeta para decirme que ya existe?

Alguna idea por favor

Comment: Depende de que ruta le estes dando. Si no le das ninguna, probablemente en `bin/debug/` dentro de la carpeta del proyecto

Comment: Abre una ventana de CMD en la carpeta del proyecto (donde está el .sln), y ejecuta `dir wrapper /a /s /b`. Con eso deberías ver realmente cualquier carpeta con ese nombre en cualquier subcarpeta, aun si está oculta o es de sistema. Si esto no sirve, agrega una captura de pantalla, porque es muy extraño.

Answer (score 0):

en el explorador de archivos ir a

> Vista > Opciones > Ver > Archivos y Carpetas Ocultas > Mostrar
>   Archivos, carpetas y unidades ocultas

en el VS

> Proyecto > Mostrar todos los archivos

Comment: Hmm. Creo que esto no responde a la pregunta del OP. Por un lado, no es que la carpeta que trata de crear esté oculta, es que no la encuentra. Por otro, "Mostrar todos los archivos" en el VS en ningun caso va a mostrar una carpeta que se crea en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: a que te refieres con "en tiempo de ejecución" quien pregunta no menciona que es su programa el que crea las carpetas, da a entender que es el mismo de forma manual creando las carpetas al menos así lo entendí yo

Comment: *"dar a entender"* no es suficiente. ante dudas, es mejor comentarlo bajo la pregunta para que el OP aclare la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Bueno, ahi tienes razón, yo interpreté que la carpeta se creaba en código, pero tal vez esté equivocado, lo que personalmente me indica que la pregunta tal vez no está lo suficientemente clara para recibir una respuesta :)

Comment: Hola yo estoy intentando crear una carpeta llamada "wrapper" debajo de uno de los 3 proyectos de mi solución y me dice que ya existe y al final he tenido que crea una llamada "wrappers" pero yo esa carpeta "wrapper" no la veo ni mostrando archivos ocultos en el explorador de archivos ni todos los archivos en el VS